# Java New Session For Each Request?

Tags: java, servlets

I have been having an issue with session variables not being available when a request has come from a domain name as opposed to localhost. For instance, if I set a user variable:

```
request.getSession(true).setAttribute("user", user);
//Redirects to another html page or something...
```

When the client makes another request and I attempt to access the user session variable it returns null.

```
//Client makes another request to the server
request.getSession(true).getAttribute("user"); //returns null
```

I've noticed that on each request, a new JSESSIONID cookie is set and the ID value changes. Does this mean that a new session is being created each time the client accesses the server? How do I maintain the same session between the client so I can store objects in the HttpSession and have access to them?

I don't know if this  has anything to do with anything either, but when viewing the application from the tomcat manager, the sessions count continues to grow regardless of the fact that I am using the application from the same browser window, not refreshing the page or anything. Another sign that a new session is being created on each request to the server?

This only happens when accessing the application from a domain name ex: example.com/app. When coming from localhost, the session variables work fine.

**Update**

I tested without using response.sendRedirect and the session variable is available until I switch pages and make another request to the server. This confirms my suspicions that a new session is being created with each request. Its not the redirect thats killing the session, its any new request. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the path in the JSESSIONID cookie. I still can't figure out why it was being set to the tomcat application path /tomcat-app-name/ but I changed the cookie configuration in the web.xml to:

```
<session-config>
  <cookie-config>
     <name>JSESSIONID</name>
     <path>/</path>
     <http-only>true</http-only>
     <secure>true</secure>
  </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

And now the session variables are working across sessions. Of course, now the session variables don't work when running using localhost. Instead you can set the sessionCookiePath on the context.xml root context node:

I'm using ubuntu server and tomcat7. For tomcat7, the context.xml can be found at /etc/tomcat7/context.xml.

```
<Context ... sessionCookiePath="/" > ... </Context>
```

Now, you should be able to run locally (if you didn't change that cookiepath on your local machine) as well as on the server without having to configure the JSESSIONID cookie in your apps web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing the redirect? Are you calling HttpServletResponse.encodeRedirectURL() beforehand?

Read [the javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeRedirectURL%28java.lang.String%29)

You would use it like `response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(path));`

Comment: To redirect to another page I am using response.sendRedirect(path). Should I be using something different?

Comment: encodeRedirectUrl is deprecated, encodeRedirectURL is not (note how it ends with URL not Url. And yes you need to call it before doing a redirect. Something like sendRedirect(encodeRedirectURL(path)).