# Session strangely returns null

Tags: javascript, java, spring, angular, spring-mvc

I save data to the session, but then I try to read it back, and it's null.
Spring MVC is my back-end and Angular 4 is the front end.

Java:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3009", allowCredentials = "true")
@RequestMapping(value = "api")
public class RestController {

@Autowired
MainLogic mainLogic;

@RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Data> getData(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){

    // user is null here )-:
    User user = (User)httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("user");

    if (user == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return mainLogic.getData();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public LoginResult logIn(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password){

    LoginResult result = mainLogic.logIn(username, password);

    if (result.getUser() != null) {
    // user is not null here
        httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute("user", result.getUser());
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Angular:

```
logIn(username: string, password: string): Observable<LoginResult>{
    let result = this.http
      .post(`${this.baseUrl}/login?username=${username}&password=${password}` , {headers: configuration.getHeaders(), withCredentials: true})
      .map(response => response.json());

    return result;
  }

getData(): Observable<Affiliate[]>{
    let results = this.http
      .get(`${this.baseUrl}/data`, {headers: configuration.getHeaders(), withCredentials: true})
      .map(response => response.json());

    return results;
  }
```

Any idea what I'm missing here? Maybe something with the CORS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java New Session For Each Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067787/java-new-session-for-each-request)

Comment: can you check if the httpServletRequest.getSession() returns the same object in both cases?

Comment: @user7294900 just tried it, and it didn't help

Comment: @alexd it's not, in the second time it's a different session

Comment: @alexd maybe something related to CORS?

Answer (score 0):

can you check if cookies are enabled?

Comment: Do you mean in the browser? Yes they are.